# How to make other line indent using css?

Tags: css

I cau use text-indent indent the first line, now I hope to make indent for other lines, so I use the following code.
but, I don't think the code is good, could you give me some suggestions? Thanks!

```
<style type="text/css">
    .Item {
       margin-top:4px;  
       margin-bottom:4px; 
       margin-left:20px;
       text-indent:-20px;         
    } 
</style>
```

Comment: what's your html? and code doesn't go bad, the developers do...

Comment: do you want to like indent a block of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is `padding`

If you just want it on the left side (like an indent) then do `padding-left: 20px`

If you want it other places you can use any padding syntax's from below:

```
padding-left: left;
padding-right: right;
padding-top: top;
padding-bottom: bottom;
padding: top right bottom left;
padding: top rightAndLeft bottom;
padding: topAndBottom leftAndRight;
padding: all;
```

Ex.

```
padding: 10px 20px 30px;
```

Will give 10px top, 20px right and left (each) and 30px bottom.

[Take a look here for more info](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Ok i think from looking at the code you were trying to indent the first line backward and not inward. 
**How it looks:** http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/MdbJd/1/embedded/result/

Take a look at this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MdbJd/

What you need to do is set `padding:5px; or whatever`. or `width:`.

Margin is for everything outside of element.